# how to prevent $location in controller changing hash

Tags: angularjs, location, hashtag

The site is build in angularjs but the visualization is coded seperately not in angularjs.
When adding $location to the controller of the app, it changes the hash-part in the url from

```
app/#hashpart
```

to

```
app/#/hashpart
```

Is there a way to prevent this? The visualization is creating and interpreting the first version and when I call my_function (that builds my site and calls the visualization):

```
$scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function(event) {
    $scope.my_function(location.hash.substr(2));
});
```

then the browser switches between both hash-versions for eternety.

Comment: Search for html5mode, its better to use that. It removes # from url

Comment: Thank you @PranavJindal!

Comment: ah can you write this as an answer, then i can close it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use html5mode in angular js. This removes # from url.

You need to make changes at server that whenever any page is requested, always reply with index.html, otherwise 404 will be encountered. (search for url rewrite rules for your server)

Comment: Thank you :D and greetings from cologne :)